# I can login a webpage (aspx) with python but i can't with JSoup

Tags: java, python, http, python-requests, jsoup

```
import requests as rq

url = "https://ogrotomasyon.uludag.edu.tr/login.aspx?un="
data = { "__EVENTTARGET" : "", "__EVENTARGUMENT" : "",
        "__VIEWSTATE" : "",
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" : "C2EE9ABB",
        "__EVENTVALIDATION" : "",
        "un":"USERNAME", "pw":"PASSWORD", "ok22": "Giriş"}

s = rq.Session()
a = s.get(url, verify=0)
print(a.text)
d1 = input()
d2 = input()
data["__VIEWSTATE"] = d1
data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = d2
a = s.post(url, data=data, verify=0)
s.get(a.url)
print(a.url)
```

I can login the system with this code when i copy __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION truely.

**CAREFULL :** I'm using one session. If i use just 'rq.get("URL")' i cannot log in. I have to use one and always same session

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection.Response first = Jsoup.connect("https://ogrotomasyon.uludag.edu.tr/login.aspx")
                .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();


        Elements form = first.parse().select("form");
        Elements inputs = form.select("input");

        System.out.println(inputs.get(0).id() + " " + inputs.get(0).val());
        System.out.println(inputs.get(1).id() + " " + inputs.get(1).val());
        System.out.println(inputs.get(2).id() + " " + inputs.get(2).val());
        System.out.println(inputs.get(3).id() + " " + inputs.get(3).val());
        System.out.println(inputs.get(4).id() + " " + inputs.get(4).val());
        System.out.println(inputs.get(7).id() + " " + inputs.get(7).val());



        Document second = Jsoup.connect("https://ogrotomasyon.uludag.edu.tr/login.aspx")
                .validateTLSCertificates(false)
               .data(inputs.get(0).id(), inputs.get(0).val())
               .data(inputs.get(1).id(), inputs.get(1).val())
               .data(inputs.get(2).id(), inputs.get(2).val())
               .data(inputs.get(3).id(), inputs.get(3).val())
               .data(inputs.get(4).id(), inputs.get(4).val())
               .data("un", "USERNAME")
               .data("pw", "PASSWORD")
               .data(inputs.get(7).id(), inputs.get(7).val())
               .post();
        System.out.println(second.text());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

But i can't log in with this code. Actually sometimes i can but few times it "throws java.net.UnknownHostException"

How can i connect via 2nd code?

Comment: I can connect with first response (in java code) everytime. But mostly it throws error when connecting second time

Comment: You have to use `bs4` to get the input values, just like you did with java. You can't use `input()` for `d1` and `d2` because it's not the same session.

Comment: The python code is not important for me now. I can write code more easly with python so i've wrote python code. I mean the python code can log in but java code can't. Why?

Comment: Try with cookies, ie `first.cookies()`

Comment: Thanks. It's the solution. :) Do you know why?